# Char bot Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, artificial-intelligence

I tried making an AI chat bot in Python language using PyCharm IDE via the code given below. But, there is an error coming of tensoflow regarding cuda.

I was following tutorial of NeuralNine.
Here is the link of the video -> https://youtu.be/1lwddP0KUEg

This was my code of `intents.json`

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['!','?','.',',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
for pattern in intent['patterns']:
    word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
    words.append(word_list)
    documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
    if intent ['tag'] not in classes:
        classes.append(intent['tag'])
```

This was my code of main.py(Given above)

```
{"intents":  [
{"tag": "greetings",
"patterns": ["hello","hey","hi","good day","namaste","greetings","whats up?","how is it 
 going?"],
"responses": ["Hello!","Hey!","What can I do for you?","Greetings!","Welcome!"]
},
{"tag": "name",
"patterns": ["what's you name?","what is your name?","what are you called?","What can I call 
 you?"],
"responses": ["My name is Misa, The AI chatbot.","You can call me Misa, The AI chatbot."]
},
{"tag": "inventor",
"patterns": ["Who made you?","By whom were you made","Who is your inventor","Who controls 
 you?","Who is your master?"],
"responses": ["I was made by NetBreakINC."]
 }
]}
```

This was the error

```
2021-06-15 13:09:29.606510: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] 
Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

2021-06-15 13:09:29.607208: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above 
cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: These are not errors but warnings (See the W and I in there?).

Comment: Do you have a GPU? If not, this message *Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine*  tells you to ignore the other one.